# Is it possible to get TeXlive version year, and preferably user platform, from within document?

Tags: luatex, texlive

Is it possible for a `lualatex` document to learn the version year of the binary, from within the document, without using shell escape? Even better if I could also detect the user's platform.

I know that it is possible to detect the date of a particular package, and possibly issue a warning if it is too old. But that is not what I need. What I have is a custom document class (not on CTAN) that comes with some non-TeX extras. I want to print a message to Terminal, reminding users that they should use one of the extras (which possibly depends on year of binary, and platform).

The binary may be either `luatex` or `luahbtex`, using `latex` format.

Pseudo-code MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} % Compile with lualatex.
\usepackage{fontspec}
\edef\whatbinary{\get\year\of\texlive\binary} % Such as 2023, 2024. OK if longer date.
\edef\whatplatform{\is\this\linux\mac\windows}
\begin{document}
Your TeXlive version year is \whatbinary.\par
You are running it on \whatplatform.
\end{document}
```

Of course, being pseudo-code, the above does not compile.

Comment: you can read the banner and extract the date. `\luatexbanner`.

Comment: texlive is (mostly) a distribution mechanism not a source repository so the texlive year is not that relevant to anything (and incomparable with other distributions) what matters is if you have luatex 1.17 or 1.18 (which is same as  asking if texlive 2023 or 2024 but a better question to ask, so I answered that question instead:-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image]

[image]

"unix" here has to be taken quite loosely.

```
\documentclass{article} % Compile with anything.
\begin{document}
binary/format is  \UseName{c_sys_engine_format_str} \UseName{c_sys_engine_version_str}

You are running it on \UseName{c_sys_platform_str} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works great. The `unix` is OK, because the exta non-TeX code has a POSIX-compatible script that should work on anything in that general category. My own device (Termux, jailed Linux on Android) shows `unix`. And I saw your above comment about version number rather than year, which is useful and helpful. My own level of coding is primitive: Only recently, I learned that I can define a new macro `\foo`, but not `\bar`, because `\bar` is already defined. :)

Comment: @rallg as long as you use latex commands, latex would have told you that.

Comment: Should we add something to `l3sys-query` in this area? Could get TL year for example.

Comment: @JosephWright as I commented under the question I don't think a document should be asking about the texlive year, in most cases.

Comment: @JosephWright As David noted, the year (as I originally asked) is probably not as informative as the binary version, for my own situation.

Answer (score 8):

If you want the release year of TeX Live you're currently running, you can get the path to a file that surely exists, namely `plain.tex`, which is possible without enabling the unrestricted shell.

Then you can easily extract the year from that path.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\str_new:N \l__railg_tlyear_str
\sys_get_shell:nnN { kpsewhich ~ plain.tex } { \cctab_select:N \c_str_cctab } \l__railg_tlyear_str
\regex_replace_once:nnN { [^[:digit:]]*([[:digit:]]{4}).* } { \1 } \l__railg_tlyear_str
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\tlyear}{}{\str_use:N \l__railg_tlyear_str}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

You're running \TeX~Live \tlyear.

\end{document}
```

[image]

If I switch to an earlier distribution, I get the expected result.

You can alternatively make a table of the executable versions.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ifcsname NewExpandableDocumentCommand\endcsname\else\usepackage{xparse}\fi

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_case:nnF { V }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\gettlyear}{}
 {
  \str_if_exist:NTF \c_sys_engine_version_str
   {
    \str_case:VnF \c_sys_engine_str
     {
      {pdftex}{\railg_gettlyear_pdftex:}
      {luatex}{\railg_gettlyear_luatex:}
      {xetex}{\railg_gettlyear_xetex:}
     }
   }
   {TeX~Live~older~than~2018}
 }

\cs_new:Nn \railg_gettlyear_pdftex:
 {
  \str_case:VnF \c_sys_engine_version_str
   {
    {1.40.26}{2024}
    {1.40.25}{2023}
    {1.4.24}{2022}
    {1.4.23}{2021}
    {1.4.21}{2020}
    {1.4.20}{2019}
    {1.4.19}{2018}
   }
   {SORRY,~bad~string}
 }
\cs_new:Nn \railg_gettlyear_luatex:
 {
  \str_case:VnF \c_sys_engine_version_str
   {
    {1.18.0}{2024}
    {1.17.0}{2023}
    {1.15.0}{2022}
    {1.13.2}{2021}
    {1.12.0}{2020}
    {1.10.0}{2019}
    {1.07.0}{2018}
   }
   {SORRY,~bad~string}
 }
\cs_new:Nn \railg_gettlyear_xetex:
 {
  \str_case:VnF \c_sys_engine_version_str
   {
    {0.999996}{2024}
    {0.999995}{2023}
    {0.999994}{2022}
    {0.999993}{2021}
    {0.999992}{2020}
    {0.999991}{2019}
    {0.99999}{2018}
   }
   {SORRY,~bad~string}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\typeout{Running TeX Live \gettlyear}

\end{document}
```

This supports `pdftex`, `luatex` and `xetex` back to 2018 (which is as far as possible); it could be supplemented or `ptex` and `eptex`. It relies on the fact that TeX Live never changes executables in its life cycle.

Comment: Ah. I had already tried getting the year from some other packages, but they are not necessarily dated to the same year as the binaries. I had not thought of `plain.tex`.

Comment: However, that may not work with some distros. For example, I run TeXlive in a jailed Linux on Android, using Termux. The year of TeXlive is not part of the path to anything, due to the custom nature of the installation.

Comment: @rallg I added a table version based on the version of the executables.

Answer (score 6):

You can extract data from `\luatexbanner`:

```
\def\texliveyear{\expandafter\texliveyearA\luatexbanner}
\def\texliveyearA #1(#2 #3 #4){#4}

The \TeX{}live distribution is: \texliveyear.

\bye
```