TeX processor version check/assertion?
I want to make sure my document (or document class) is being processed by a recent-enough XeLaTeX. Is this at all possible?
I know there's a \IfPackageAtLeast LaTeX kernel command, apparently; what about something similar for the processor?
(I'd accept both an answer which checks the processor name and the version, or just the version.)

Do you want to check the engine, the format or both? \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2021-11-15] for the LaTeX format typically seen at the top of class/package files. \XeTeXversion? Or there are the \sys_... conditionals in expl3?

@cfr: What does the "format" mean? My document class basically requires XeLaTeX, and without it compilation just fails anyway, but an inappropriate version can trigger output glitches.

by the format means the version of latex running on xetex such as the June 2024 release, or you can check the underlying vesion of xetex itself such as egreg showed with a version number 0.99999something but in practice that never changes much so unless it's 10? years old and only has 256 interchar token classes, that is probably not so interesting version information

why do you need to restrict to xelatex? can't you make the documentclass work with luatex as well? (if you can only support one, I'd pick luatex)

@DavidCarlisle: To be honest - it's a document class I wrote 12 years ago and I'm just maintaining it. Never tried compiling it with LuaTeX. I want compilation failures to be more informatives so that users don't have to file gratuitous bugs.

making it work for luatex as well as xetex would probably be needed at some point, eg if you get a requirement for accessible tagged pdf

@DavidCarlisle: I would be extremely gratified if my alma mater actually bothered to make any requirements of thesis PDFs... but I would appreciate a link to some kind of guidance of how to make documents luatex-compatible (beyond trial-and-error).

most documents that work with xelatex will work unchanged with lualatex unless you are using \XeTeXintercharclass so no general guidance needed but if you try and get a specific error you could ask about that. (If you are using the xetex inter character token feature then switching to luatex can be tricky as there is no direct replacement)

@DavidCarlisle: Ok, I guess I'll just try it at some point....

unless of course you have filled the files with xetex version checks so they error in luatex...

@DavidCarlisle: if (using xelatex) then if (version is too low) then error.

the only significant change in xetex in the last 20 years is the change in the number of char classes, and very few documents need more than 256 classes so the chance that anyone has a version of xetex that is too old is essentially zero

@DavidCarlisle: It could be that what I should really be checking for is package versions then.

\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\showengineandversion}{}
 {
  Engine:~\c_sys_engine_str;~version:~\c_sys_engine_version_str \par
  \sys_get_shell:nnN { kpsewhich~-var-value=SELFAUTOLOC } {} \l_tmpa_tl
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l_tmpa_seq { / } \l_tmpa_tl
  Year:~\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 5 } \par
  Platform:~\texttt{\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {-1}}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\showengineandversion

\end{document}

Now I compile with different releases of TeX Live




The value stored in \c_sys_engine_version_str, when the engine is xetex is good for comparison with floating point numbers.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\fp_compare:nF { \c_sys_engine_version_str >= 0.999994 }
 {
  \iow_term:n { You~need~XeTeX~at~least~version~0.999994.~Boom! }
  \stop
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Test

\end{document}

If I run the current TeX Live version, the file compiles normally. With TeX Live 2021 I get on the terminal
You need XeTeX at least version 0.999994. Boom!
 )
No pages of output.


Could I trouble you to add such a comparison of \c_sys_engine_version_str?

@einpoklum Added.

I guess it's platform dependent, but on my windows machine the year is the 3rd item in the sequence, not 5th

@mbert This was just a cheap test. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/713743/4427
